# Naming unique distributions

Tags: distributions, terminology

Assume the number of flowers at a study site follows a poisson distribution. Then assume insects arrive and destroy the flowers. The number of flowers killed follows a negative-binomial distribution.

So the final distribution of flowers results from one original distribution that's been affected by another process. What type of distribution do we call this final distribution?

At first, I thought it might be a **mixture distribution** but it seems like that only applies in cases where you add two distributions. Also, I'm sure it's not a **compound distribution** because that assumes some parameter of the original distribution is modeled by another distribution.

Comment: Let the random variable $X$ represent the number of flowers, which has an observed value of $x$; for example, $6$, say. Then the number of flowers killed $Y$ has a maximum possible value of $x$ ($6$), while the negative binomial is not bounded above at any finite $x$, so $Y$ cannot actually be negative binomial.

Comment: I would still call it a negative binomial distribution. That's because a NB distribution approximates the Poisson when theta approaches infinity (NB variance = lambda + lambda^2/theta). So it seems like negative binomial is already compound sort of? Interesting question!

Comment: Glen_b, you do raise a good point. Let's rather say each study site is subjected to insect attack in a (tentatively) negative-binomial fashion - but if the reduction amounts happens to be more than the amount of flowers available for attack, it defaults to 0 flowers remaining for that site (as opposed to a negative number of flowers). So the insect attack process will be a truncated neg-bin and the final distribution will be zero-inflated.

Comment: The truncated model looks physically unrealistic, but its censored version would make a lot of sense--and correspond to many other models of censoring involving variable (random) censoring limits.

Comment: I'm not aware of a specific name. I'd probably call it something like "a negative binomial random variable randomly censored by a Poisson", but there may be a better way to put it.